# Swift random number

Tags: random, swift, swift-playground

I'm having problems with this drawRandomCard function.

It works just like it should for some time, but eventually it crashes the application.

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation


var cardDeck = Array<PlayingCard>()

class Deck {

    func addCard(card : PlayingCard , atTop : Bool = false){

        if atTop {
            cardDeck.insert(card, atIndex: 0);
        }else{
            cardDeck += card
        }
    }

    func drawRandomCard() -> PlayingCard{
        var card = PlayingCard()
        var randomNumber : Int = Int(arc4random()) % (cardDeck.count - 1)
        card = cardDeck[randomNumber]
        cardDeck.removeAtIndex(randomNumber)
        return card
    }

}
```

Comment: How does your code crash? Is there a stack trace or error message? Your code as posted on Github seems to have a number of compilation errors.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `arc4random_uniform` to avoid modulo bias. Like following:

```
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(150)
```

For your example, it will be:

```
let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cardDeck.count)))
```

Comment: Factually correct, but entirely unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Kevin Not well explained, but it _is_ related to the question.  Adam's answer won't overflow a Swift `Int`

Answer (score -4):

Try this: `Int(rand())` instead of `arc4random()`

Comment: How would this alleviate the crashing? I'm not saying it doesn't, but without an explanation I don't see the difference.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, worked really well.

Comment: the arc4random() don't work well with Int type

Comment: missing any kind of explanation why to use rand instead of arc4random

Comment: The amazing thing about this really bad answer is that it has two up votes! To be clear:` rand()` is a terrible random number generator and requires seeding, it should not be used. `arc4random()` and `arc4random_uniform()` generate cryptographically good random numbers and require no seeding.